# 2D Array in Java, Indexed by Characters

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Unless I'm mistaken, it is legal to have an array in Java indexed by character values, since these are equivalent to 8-bit numbers. However, the following code generates error messages for me:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[256][256];
myArray['%']['^'] = 25;
```

Is there a way to make this work?

**edit**: Wow, I really didn't do a good job of copying over the code.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more effective using a Map?  You're basically using a map anyways--using the hash values of characters to index your array.

Comment: Perhaps. What's the easiest way of making a pair of keys in Java, then (since there aren't native tuple, like in Python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not illegal because in Java (and other languages), the char in this case will be casted to an int. Such as `(int)'%'`

Something like this would be safer if you don't know what type of char value it will be.

```
int[][] myArray = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE][Character.MAX_VALUE];
myArray['%']['^'] = 24;
```

It will work since Java will translate that to:

```
myArray[37][94] = 24;
```

Make sure you place [max value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of char (as already done) which is basically, '?' which translates to 65535. Or you will get an [ArrayOutOfBoundsException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

If you know your range, you can still use 256. Just make sure you do proper bounds checking where the input is >=0 and < 256.

```
public int getItem(int x, int y) {
  if ((x < 0 && x > 255) || (y < 0 && y > 255)) {
    return -1; // Or you can throw an exception such as InvalidParameterException
  }
  return myArray[x, y];
}
```

Error bounds checking plays an important role for this.

I would rethink what your trying to do, something like this is unreadable, what are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you can use a different [collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)?

*EDIT*

Changed the types since you changed the code.

Comment: Heh. The feasibility of this approach is silly in most cases though. I +1'd, but the total space requirements should be mentioned (2 * 2^16 * 2^16 = 2^33 = ^^ ). The original question makes it sound like only the characters in a given range `[0,255)` should be used -- so perhaps address that too.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are equivalent to unsigned 16-bit integer, but that's really an awful design flaw in Java and shouldn't be abused. Conceptually, the `char` type stands for a character, not some integral value that happens to be mapped to a character (or even to a part of a character, in case of surrogate pairs).

The Map interface should be used to map something to something. Arrays should only be used when the index type is a full-fledged integer type, meaning to be used as such. And when these indexes don't fit into a fixed interval, so you don't know the array size in advance, it's better to use a Map for mapping integers either, rather than resizing the array each time.

Also consider memory usage. For 8-bit characters (ASCII) you can get away with 256x256x4 = 256K bytes of memory. But you kill the very possibility of internationalizing your application this way, which is a serious crime. To support the whole 16-bit range you'll need 64Kx64Kx4 = 16G bytes! And you still won't have the full support for characters outside that range, but then again you won't have it with a Map either, that's Java's flaw, not yours. It's not that it is needed by many anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works (i mean it compiles):

```
int[][] myArray = new int[256][256];
myArray['%']['^'] = 10;
```

Errors:

1. you have different names for the arrays: first is `myArray` and the second is named `table`
2. myArray is an array of arrays of `int` but you assigned a string to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

For [reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html), a Java `char` is a [16-bit unsigned](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1) quantity that is a [valid array index](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.4), and ["An Array of Characters is Not a String"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.9)