# Triples in Java

Tags: java, tuples, triples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Java need tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457775/does-java-need-tuples)

Does Java support triples or at least pairs? Does Java support tuples? I am trying to find a way to make a list so that it has a triple with initial point as first, terminal point at last, and distance in the middle. However, I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128376/alternatives-to-2d-arrays-in-java/5128420#5128420

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually just create my own class for these purposes.

```
class Pair<A,B> {
    A a;
    B b;
    public Pair( A a, B b ) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I did just end up making my own classes

Answer (score 5):

If you have three related values like that it implies me that you will need a method or two that deal with them.

You will always find your code better and cleaner if you just go ahead and make a real class to contain these values rather than try to create some structure.

Then do all the good class stuff you can--make the variables private, initialize it in the constructor and make them final if you can (immutable), add methods that manipulate your data directly to the class rather than adding getters wherever possible, ...

This usually opens up great opportunities for further refactoring and code reuse.

It's always tempting to not create a class in cases like this but in my experience that temptation is always some evil demon trying to inject havoc into your code.  Just do it the right way to start...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing